# auto kill a shell buffer when command finishes

Tags: shell, functions

i have this function you guys helped me write

```
 (defun z/dired-shell-other-window-beets ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((command (concat "beet import " (format "%S" (dired-get-filename)))))
     (switch-to-buffer (shell)
       (insert command)
       (comint-send-input))))
```

is there a way to 1. rename the buffer to *beets* when created and 2.auto close (kill) the *beets* buffer when the command i run `beet import` finishes running?

Comment: Do you actually want the buffer at all (e.g. to see the output of the beet command)? If not there are better ways of running commands than starting  a shell window, To directly answer the first part of your question, use `(shell "beets")`.

Comment: thx @icarus. for various reasons yes i would like to get the buffer output and see it. sometimes beets will ask questions interactively and thus its needed. thx.

Comment: How about using `start-process` and a `process-sentinel` instead of a shell; or, `start-process-shell-command`?  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html  And, here is the link for sentinels:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html  With the process sentinel, you can monitor the output for things like a finished signal.  With a process filter, you can monitor additional output.

Answer (score 2):

**CAVEAT**:  The two snippets below are examples using the function `ls` that is available on most *nix systems.  Copy and paste snippets to the `*scratch*` buffer, place the cursor immediately following the last parentheses of either snippet, and press:  `C-x C-e` (aka `eval-last-sexp`).

The following snippet is an example using the function `shell` to process a string with `comint-simple-send`:

```lisp
(let ((kill-buffer-query-functions nil)
      (buf (shell "*OUTPUT-BUFFER*")))
   (comint-simple-send buf "ls -la")
   (sit-for 2)
   (kill-process (get-buffer-process buf))
   (when (and (not (one-window-p)) (get-buffer-window buf))
      (delete-window (get-buffer-window buf)))
   (kill-buffer buf))
```

---

The following snippet is with `start-process` and `set-process-sentinel`:

```lisp
(set-process-sentinel
  (start-process
    "my-process-name"
    "*OUTPUT-BUFFER*"
    "ls"
    "-la")
  (lambda (p e)
    (when (= 0 (process-exit-status p))
      (let ((buf (process-buffer p)))
        (when (get-buffer buf)
          (display-buffer buf t)
          (sit-for 2)
          (delete-window (get-buffer-window buf))
          (kill-buffer buf))))))
```